# android application storage

Tags: android, storage

when I go into settings -> downloaded ->

and I look under "Storage"

I see: Total, Application and Data.

Where does it get Application from.  If I look under /data/data/com.company.app, I can see the data storage, but for Application, if I look under /data/app/com.company.app.apk -- the install image, but that's not the same size as what settings Application Info reports...

Does Android run straight from the apk/zip file or does it expand it somewhere and run from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apps don't run directly from the .apk, they are decompressed and JIT-compiled to the "Dalvik cache"